# Android app that will survey me at specific or random intervals

Tags: android, notification, survey

Many times I've wished there was a simple app that would let me collect data on myself throughout the day. Most recently, I'd like to use it to track my energy levels throughout the day.

The solution I need would:

- Allow me to build surveys inside the app
- Let me specify how often to remind me to enter data both by interval ("every hour") and randomly ("10 times a day")
- Allow me to tap the notification to go directly to data input
- Allow me to view and export the data

I know a few years ago "Quantified Self" was all the rage, so I feel like this must exist, but I've never been able to find it.